# How to define different routes for global and non-global zone to the same destination?

Tags: routing, solaris-zones

I have the requirement to separate the management network for global and non global zones in a Solaris 10 server. The global zone has its own management network and all non-global zones share their one management network, which is different from the one of the global zone. Take the following addresses as an example:

```
global zone:       10.0.1.1/24
non-global zone 1: 10.0.2.1/24
non-global zone 2: 10.0.2.2/24
non-global zone 3: 10.0.2.3/24
non-global zone 4: 10.0.2.4/24
and so on ...
```

The router in the management network of the global zone is 10.0.1.254 and the router in the management network of the non-global zones is 10.0.2.254.

All zones shall communicate with the same management infrastructure 10.10.1.0/24. But the the communication should go via different routes. The global zone should go via 10.0.1.254 and the non global zones should go via 10.0.2.254.

The question is: is the possible with shared interfaces? I know that this will be possible with exclusive interfaces for the zones. But I have more than 10 zones and not enough interfaces. So I have to use shared interfaces.

I know the `defrouter` option of `zonecfg` but this will not help, because the default gateways point to the Internet and not the management network. I need the `defrouter` functionality for routes. I need to define a route which works only for the traffic coming from the zone in the same way `defrouter` does it for the default gateway. But I can not find a solution.